# UML2 for eclipse

Tags: uml

Can any one help me get eclipse repository of UML2 ? I could not get the link can some one help please?

Thanks,
Lalith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/downloads/?showAll=1&hlbuild=R201009141451&project=uml2#R201009141451

this is the zip file download site. How do i install this zip file ?

Comment: Well inside the zip file there is a site.xml file . inside that they have the original http link to this site.xml. Just use this in installer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Eclipse Update Manager. In Eclipse go to the following menu item:

`Help > Install New Software`

You will see something like the following dialog box appear. You might have to Add a site: http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/updates/releases/. Then select `UML2` from the `Modeling` section to install.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can go here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2-Tool-Compatibility
and download one of the tools that extend the UML2 component (all of them use exactly the same storage format but add a different user interface). For instance, take a look at MOSKitt.

Some of these tools come prepackaged so there´s nothing to install, just download and execute them